# API call in loop

Tags: php, api

Im making a big APi call, i have over 6000 records. Out of those 6000 i get 200 per  page. So if we divide 6000 by 200 we get 30 pages in total.

So if I would want to get all records I'd need to make 30 different requests. I can speficy the amount per page in my request url parameters. Right now it looks like this:

```
$getRequest = $CallMonkeyApi->makeApiCall('GET','/address/get-all?apiKey=secret&page=1&size=200');
```

In the url you see a parameter "page=1" I would like this number to be dynamic from a loop that stops at 30. But I dont know where to start.

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) may help

Comment: do you know that the end page will always be 30?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs for now i only need 30

Comment: Any loop will do. With that said, if possible try to get a bigger batch. Doing API calls in a loop can put unnecessary stress on the API.

Comment: then a for loop as Federico linked will do.

Comment: It sounds very dangerous to assume 6000. Is there no api that you can call to ask how many you have? Does the API not tell you somewhere in its response how many you have?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i know the exact amount of records, its documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a "for" loop

```
//An array for results
$getRequests = array();

//For every occurance where `x` is less than or equal to 30
for( $x = 1; $x<=30; $x++ ){
    //Build the path to API call
    $path = "/address/get-all?apiKey=secret&page=" . $x . "&size=200";

    //Make API call and store the output on the $getRequests array of results
    $getRequests[] = $CallMonkeyApi->makeApiCall('GET', $path);
}
```

Then you can access your `$getRequests` array by using `$getRequests[$pageNumber]`. So, for example, if I wanted to see page 5, i'd do `print_r( $getRequests[4] )`.

Note that the page number will be one less in the array because arrays start at 0.